# PHP if($d=2) not working

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, integer, comparison

Already found the issue. Thanks guys. Please stop down voting now. I get it. Bad question.

I'm doing a simple while loop and there's an if statement inside that's not working... and I have no idea why. Here's the loop and the statement:

```
$d = 1;
while($d <= 2) {
    if($d = 2) {
        $dayznum = $dayznum2;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the loop executes twice, but `$dayznum` ALWAYS `= $daysnum2` and I can't figure out why.

Additional info:

`$d` is not used anywhere else in the script
`$dayznum` and `$dayznum2` are both `integers`

Comment: Turns out it's none of these. My bad buys. $dayznum and $dayznum2 are global variables. It was a difft part of the code screwing it up. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot tho!

Comment: `$d = 2` **is** working. It assigned the value `2` to the variable `$d` and checked, if the operation was a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if condition checking must be done using `==` or `===` operator.Because `=` is used to assign something.So try this

```
if($d == 2){
   $dayznum = $dayznum2;
}
```

Comment: This just breaks my loop.

Comment: Of course it does. But because your logic is wrong, not because this answer is. You aren't changing the value of $d anywhere, resulting in this snippet being an infinite loop.

Comment: This snippet wasn't the full loop obviously, but touche. Found the issue tho. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You have only used one `=` when it should `==`.

```
$d = 1;
while($d <= 2){

    if($d == 2){
        $dayznum = $dayznum2;
    }
}
```

You could use `===` if you want to check type as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems.

### 1.

```
if($d = 2) //Problem : = is an assignment operator , you should use == or ===
```

change to

```
if($d == 2) // Make use of == or === for checking.
```

### 2.

Increment the value of `$d` inside the **`while`** loop *[Else you will run into an infinite loop]*

Rewrite like this.

```
$d = 1;
while($d <= 2){
    if($d == 2){$dayznum = $dayznum2;}
$d++; // Increment here.
}
```

Comment: Tried this. It's still doing it.

Comment: Increment $d inside the loop

Comment: @CriketX `$d++` is the **key** here.

Comment: Yah, had that in the real loop, just slipped my mind when putting it up here. issue is, the $dayznum vars are globals, and it never got put back after it was flipped. Had this while loop, inside a for loop so the first iteration was $dayznum, but everyone after that (about 40) was always $dayznum2. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Change `$d = 2` into `$d ==2` and you do not have increment statement like `$d++`. consider adding it in loop

```
$d = 1;
    while($d <= 2){
      if($d == 2){$dayznum = $dayznum2;}

      $d++; //try to add this as well
   }
```